# combobox dropbox in VBA issue

Tags: vba, excel, combobox

I have issue with `combobox.DropDown` method when use it in change event will show only 1 result with scrollbar to show the other results .

```
Private Sub emp_name_Change()
    Call Connect_to_db

    strSQL = "SELECT [Name] , [ID] FROM Table2 where [Name] Like '%" & emp_name & "%' Order By [Name]; "

    rs.Open strSQL, cn

    If rs.bof = True Or rs.EOF = True Then
        MsgBox ("No records found")
    Else
        rs.MoveFirst
    End If

    With emp_name
        .Clear
        Do While Not rs.EOF
            .AddItem rs.Fields(0).Value
            rs.MoveNext
        Loop
    End With

    Call Close_db

    emp_name.DropDown
End Sub
```

Comment: BIRDSVIEW: Wouldn't `.AddItem` re-initiate the emp_name_Change() event.

Answer (score 1):

Change `Private Sub emp_name_Change()` to `Private Sub emp_name_Click()` and also move the `With emp_name` inside the `Else` part

Try this (**UNTESTED**)

```
Private Sub emp_name_Click()
    Call Connect_to_db

    strSQL = "SELECT [Name] , [ID] FROM Table2 where [Name] Like '%" & emp_name & "%' Order By [Name]; "

    rs.Open strSQL, cn

    If rs.bof = True Or rs.EOF = True Then
        MsgBox ("No records found")
    Else
        rs.MoveFirst

        With emp_name
            .Clear
            Do While Not rs.EOF
                .AddItem rs.Fields(0).Value
                rs.MoveNext
            Loop
        End With
    End If

    Call Close_db

    emp_name.DropDown
End Sub
```

Comment: it is work with me if I change it to click or enter event . but I need it as change event 

thank you

Comment: I need just to set number of lines showed as result . I use  .DropDownLines = 0 but it is not work

Comment: ok so are you trying to create a combobox where you type a letter(s) and the list shows only those entries which start with that/those letter(s)

Comment: yes , and it works with this code . but the problem it will show only 1 iteme

Answer (score 0):

yes I need to make this with change event ..
Am trying to create a combobox where you type a letter(s) and the list shows only those entries which start with that/those letter .

I can retrieve the whole data when open the file and use advance filter . Is this best method ?